# Primes of the form $a^2+b^2+c^2$, $0<a<b<c$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

Are there results showing which prime numbers that can be expressed as the sum of three different integers greater than zero?

---

By the three square theorem of Legendre a natural number can be written as a square sum of three natural numbers if and only if it isn't of the form
$4^i(8j+7)$. where $i,j$ are natural numbers.

Due to an answer to [Conjecture: Any sufficiently big sum of three squares can be written as a square sum of three different natural numbers greater than zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344080/conjecture-any-sufficiently-big-sum-of-three-squares-can-be-written-as-a-square/3344088#3344088) there is a conjecture by Jeffrey Shallit:

> A number is a sum of 3 squares, but not a sum of 3 distinct nonzero squares, if and only if it is of the form $4^js$, where $j \ge 0$ and
>
> $s \in$
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 17, 18, 19, 22, 25, 27, 33, 34, 37, 43, 51, 57, 58, 67, 73, 82, 85, 97, 99, 102, 123, 130, 163, 177, 187, 193, 267, 627, 697}

So, if the conjecture by Shallit is true, then all primes not of the form
$8m+7$ and not belonging to
$\{2, 3, 5, 11, 13, 17, 19, 37, 43, 67, 73, 97, 163, 193\}$ can be written as a square sum of three different non zero natural numbers.

Comment: What is your motivation to ask this question? Does it appear somewhere else?

Comment: @DavoodKhajehpour - Curiosity.

Comment: Dear Lehs, Do you know the relation between this kind of numbers [numbers represented as the sum of 3 squares] and physics? I heard these numbers are related to the energy levels of atomic particles, but I am not sure. This [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360820/is-there-any-connection-between-theta-series-and-physics#comment807622_360820) tells something related.

Comment: Also, Long ago I asked 2 questions regarding this relation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360820/is-there-any-connection-between-theta-series-and-physics) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361650/from-number-theory-to-physics).

Comment: @DavoodKhajehpour - No, I didn't know that.

Comment: 187 isn't prime.

Comment: @RosieF - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing seems be known. See [OEIS/A125516](https://oeis.org/A125516). Contrast with [OEIS/A085317](https://oeis.org/A085317).